# Eclipse: Android Soundboard buttons are "overclickable"

Tags: android, eclipse, button, click

In my android soundboard, all of the buttons work perfectly and the sounds play normally, but there is a problem. The problem is that when you press a button in the app, you can press other buttons. For instance, if the button I press plays a siren like noise, I can press another button and both sounds will play at the same time. This is not what I want. Is there any code I can add to make it so that I can click only one button at a time, or some code that makes the previous sound stop and it will play the newly selected sound?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.soundboard"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.2">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"  android:debuggable="false" android:allowClearUserData="true">
    <activity android:label="Vegeta Soundboard" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="Soundboard" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

the simplest thing is to just have a soundPlaying boolean that is global that you set when the user clicks a sound button and that is unset by the end of that sound.

```
 public class Main extends Activity{




     //global variable, notice how it's not in any method or inner class
    //so it's accessible to all the members of this class
    private boolean soundPlaying = false;




     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle b){
            super.onCreate(b);
        }


    //Somewhere in here you have your onclick function that you have called from your xml button
     public void playSound(View v){
    if(soundPlaying)
       return;
    soundPlaying = true;
//myMedia is your media player object

    myMedia.start();//this will only work if you have a media player set up with media

    myMedia.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                soundPlaying = false;//here you set it to false cause the sound is done

            }
        });
    }





    }
```

Comment: Okay so I ran into another problem. How do I incorporate the global variable into the android app so that it will work when on my phone?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. What would you like to see happen when you're on your phone? Assuming you're in your app, what are you hoping will be the effect of a phone call coming in?

Comment: What I mean is how do I put the global variable into the app? Do I create a JavaScript for it, do I add it to the main.xml, or does it go in a place that I have not listed?

Comment: Just a top level boolean member of your Activity class.

Comment: Okay, I've added the manifest.xml. Where do I place the boolean value from here?

Comment: No no... this has nothing to do with any xml... I don't mean to be rude (honestly) but you seem to be unaware of how to write a simple Java class, which is all we're talking about here.  Just a global boolean member of your Activity class to hold onto the state of the sound. It's Java 101. Are you a non-programmer trying to wing something together?

Comment: You basically have got it right. I'm just trying to make an application for personal use only. Just a one time thing.

Comment: ok, well, forgive me but I can't give you a primer on Java, there are oodles of on-line sources for that sort of thing.  In your Main Activity, before the onCreate method declaration, you would just add a property like in the code sample above.  I've altered the code sample to give you an idea of what you should be seeing (roughly), but it won't work as is, you still need to understand (somewhat) what you're doing.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class newBoard extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Thank you for using this App.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // ads - load request to display
        AdView layout = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

        // ads - load display with an ad
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adRequest.setTesting(true);

        layout.loadAd(adRequest);

        // import sound files
        final MediaPlayer sound01 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound01);
        final MediaPlayer sound02 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound02);
        final MediaPlayer sound03 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound03);
        final MediaPlayer sound04 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound04);
        final MediaPlayer sound05 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound05);
        final MediaPlayer sound06 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound06);
        final MediaPlayer sound07 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound07);
        final MediaPlayer sound08 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound08);
        final MediaPlayer sound09 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound09);
        final MediaPlayer sound10 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound10);
        final MediaPlayer sound11 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound11);
        final MediaPlayer sound12 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound12);
        final MediaPlayer sound13 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound13);
        final MediaPlayer sound14 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound14);
        final MediaPlayer sound15 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound15);
        final MediaPlayer sound16 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound16);
        final MediaPlayer sound17 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound17);
        final MediaPlayer sound18 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound18);
        final MediaPlayer sound19 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound19);
        final MediaPlayer sound20 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound20);
        final MediaPlayer sound21 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound21);
        final MediaPlayer sound22 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound22);
        final MediaPlayer sound23 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound23);
        final MediaPlayer sound24 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound24);
        final MediaPlayer sound25 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound25);

        // play sound files on clicks
        Button s01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01); 
        s01.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote01));
        s01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound01.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                sound01.start();                
                }

        });
        registerForContextMenu(s01);

        Button s02 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button02); 
        s02.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote02));
        s02.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound02.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                sound02.start();
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s02);

        Button s03 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button03); 
        s03.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote03));
        s03.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound03.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                sound03.start();
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s03);

        Button s04 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button04); 
        s04.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote04));
        s04.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound04.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                sound04.start();
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s04);

        Button s05 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button05); 
        s05.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote05));
        s05.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound05.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                sound05.start();
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s05);

        Button s06 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button06); 
        s06.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote06));
        s06.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound06.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                sound06.start();
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s06);

        Button s07 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button07); 
        s07.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote07));
        s07.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound07.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                sound07.start();
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s07);

        Button s08 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button08); 
        s08.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote08));
        s08.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound08.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                sound08.start();
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s08);

        Button s09 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button09); 
        s09.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote09));
        s09.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound09.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                sound09.start();
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s09);

        Button s10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10); 
        s10.setText(this.getString(R.string.quote10));
        s10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    sound10.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                sound10.start();
            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(s10);
```

Comment: Where would the code above this go in here (your directions seemed confusing) im trying to get the same thing to happen (sorry im a noob